# How to translate "objective" as in name of section in a resume

Tags: translation

Usually resumes contain the "Objective" paragraph which provides the summary of things a person thinks he does best and what he wants to do. Will simply using 目的{もくてき} work or there is a more specific term.

Comment: Are you just making a translation or you're making a resume to be submitted to a Japanese company?

Comment: Part of a resume

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at standard Japanese 履歴書{れきりしょ} rather than translating from an English resume format.

A common section is 志望{しぼう}の動機{どうき} which is a reason for applying (to that particular job/company), and tends to contain the sort of thing you're describing - why you want to work in that field and/or for that company, combined with any skills and experience you have that makes you right for the job.